# Installing a light table(editor) in debian

Tags: software-installation, debian, text-editor

I want to install lighttable programming editor in kali Linux(debian).I have downloaded the `tar.gz` version from [here](http://www.lighttable.com).

But I am unable to install the light table .Please help in regarding this.

Comment: @jobin But in this package i have tried but there is no INSTALL named file and file name configure.

Comment: You don't have nothing to install. First extract the archive then run `LightTable`. That's it

Comment: @RaduRădeanu But it is not running.

Comment: It does not run at all....

Comment: I stopped using it and Moved to sublime.